# Invalid initialization of non-const reference from a rvalue

Tags: c++, pointers

```
MyObject& MyObject::operator++(int)
{

MyObject e;
e.setVector(this->vector);

...

return &e;
}

invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'MyObject&' from an rvalue of type 'MyObject*'
     return &e;
             ^
```

I am not sure what it's saying. Is it saying that e is a pointer, because it's not a pointer. Also, if you'd make a pointer to the address of e, it would get wiped out at the end of the bracket and the pointer would be lost.

Comment: `e` is not a pointer, but `&e` is a pointer.

Comment: I did something like this MyObject * pointer = &e; return *pointer, but the pointer disappears at some point.

Comment: Yes, you should not return a reference to a local variable. Return a copy instead.

Comment: So, I should do away with the & since I can't call the constructor with this, right? That's what I wanted to do, but I wasn't sure it would be a good idea since most people told me to return the address. I don't see what difference it would make though.

Comment: Copying an object makes a new object. The original one, the local variable, is destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return type is `MyObject&`, a reference to a (non-temporary) `MyObject` object. However, your return expression has a type of `MyObject*`, because you are getting the address of `e`.

```
return &e;
       ^
```

Still, your `operator++`, which is a **postfix** increment operator due to the dummy `int` argument, is poorly defined. In accordance to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/1619294, it should be defined more or less as

```
MyObject MyObject::operator++(int)
{
   MyObject e;
   e.setVector(this->vector);

   ...

   return e;
}
```

**without** the reference in the return type.

Comment: why do people insist on returning the address?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that `e` is not a pointer, but `&e` very much *is* a pointer.

I'm reasonably certain that returning a reference to a stack variable that will be out of scope before you can use it is also not such a good idea.

The general way to implement postfix `operator++` is to save the current value to return it, and modify `*this` with the prefix variant, such as:

```
Type& Type::operator++ ()   {   // ++x
    this->addOne();             // whatever you need to do to increment
    return *this;
}
Type Type::operator++ (int) {   // x++
    Type retval (*this);
    ++(*this);
    return retval;
}
```

Especially note the fact that the prefix variant returns a *reference* to the current object (after incrementing) while the postfix variant returns a *non-reference copy* of the original object (before incrementing).

That's covered in the C++ standard. In `C++11 13.6 Built-in operators /3`:

> For every pair `(T, VQ)`, where `T` is an arithmetic type, and `VQ` is either `volatile` or empty, there exist candidate operator functions of the form:
>
> `VQ T & operator++(VQ T &);`
>
> `T operator++(VQ T &, int);`

If, for some reason, you *can't* use the constructor to copy the object, you can still do it the way you have it (creating a local `e` and setting its vector) - you just have to ensure you return `e` (technically a *copy* of `e`) rather than `&e`.

Comment: I can't use the constructor though, because it has a vector inside it and it takes a string as an argument.

Comment: @user2967016: are you saying you don't have a constructor that takes another object of the same type? That strikes me as ... less than ideal ... design (though you may of course have good reasons for it, feel free to elucidate).

Answer (score 0):

Change `return &e;` to `return e;`. In the same way that a function like

```
void Func(int &a);
```

isn't called with `Func(&some_int)` you don't need the `&` in the return statement. `&e` takes the location of `e` and is of type `MyObject*`.

Also note, `MyObject&` is a *reference* to the object, not a copy. You are returning a reference to `e`, which will be destroyed when the function finishes and as such will be invalid when you next make use of it.